# Testing an ASP.NET application (integration, unit) using BDD

Tags: .net, capybara, jasmine, specflow, coypu

I'm wanting to do some integration tests on our ASP.NET website. I'd like to run these tests:

- Integration tests on a headless browser or selenium without having to rewrite code. Would like it to integrate with the Visual Studio 2012 Test Explorer.
- Unit tests for C# code.
- Unit tests for Javascript.

I liked the look of Jasmine and SpecFlow, but I'd like to limit the testing frameworks I have to learn. I also found [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu), which looks like it may be useful, as it is a .NET alternative to [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).

What frameworks could cover these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Try testing Specifications rather than integration testing if possible - read 'Specification by Example' (http://specificationbyexample.com/). SpecFlow is good for this in combination with Selenium (Coypu looks like a nice abstraction to put above Selenium).

- nUnit will work fine for Unit testing C# - put as much logic as you can in the Business Logic tier, so you don't have to rely on UI testing. - Use this plugin for Test Explorer VS2012 to work - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d
- QUnit/sinon.js - Javascript unit testing
- jscover - Javascript unit testing code coverage

Coypu looks cool thanks - didn't know about it!

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your first bullet point, Coypu is an excellent web driver abstraction which makes it easy to switch between different web drivers. I've been using it to great effect in a corporate environment.

It's also fairly trivial to configure it to use the PhantomJS headless webkit browser. See [this](https://github.com/featurist/coypu#phantomjs) link for how to do so.

Also a C# library I have found invaluable for unit testing is [Fluent Assertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions). Its fluent style nicely complements technology agnostic BDD tests.